# id not automatically available in PlayFramework models?

Tags: playframework-2.0

When I try to access a model in the Application class or in a model it throws the following error.  I can create the model and persist it.  But if I try and access it, problemo.

Execution exception

```
[InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'id' of bean class [models.CandidateToSalesforce]: No property 'id' found]
In [...]/app/views/syncedRecords.scala.html at line 11.

7   <h3>Results</h3>
8   <ul>
9       @for(r <- records) {
10          <li>
11              @r    [[ this is the line]]
12          </li>
13      }
14  </ul>
15}
```

This can be fixed by adding the getter as shown below.

```
@Id
public Long id;

// NOTE: play framework was bugging out without this method even though it's supposed to be automatic
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Not a huge deal but is this not wrong?  The [docs say](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaEbean) "Play has been designed to generate getter/setter automatically, to ensure compatibility with libraries that expect them to be available at runtime"

Do I have a known config problem that's going to bite me in other ways?

Comment: On line 11 in your view you are only calling `@r` or `@r.getId()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own `toString()` method in the model:

```
public String toString(){
     return this.id.toString();
}
```

although it's probably better idea to return real some string instead of ie.

```
return this.name+" "+this.somethingElse;
```

Then if you'll use `this is my record: @r` in template it will render the `toString()` return.

You can fetch your `id` w/out writing custom getter with: `@r.id` (or `r.id` in the controller)